# User Control's Picture box looses image

Tags: vb.net, image, controls

I have created a little user control which is just a label and a picturebox. (Its designed as a menu item control, many of which are added to a flow layout panel as a 'home manu')

The code for the user control is as follows:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class HomeButton
Public Event HomeButton_Click()
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
Description("HomeButtonProperties"),
Browsable(True)>
Public Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return Me.Icon_PictureBox.Image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal image As Image)
        Me.Icon_PictureBox.Image = image
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Text_Menu As String
    Get
        Return MenuText_Label.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        MenuText_Label.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Icon_PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Icon_PictureBox.Click, MenuText_Label.Click, Me.Click
    RaiseEvent HomeButton_Click()

End Sub

End Class
```

The problem i have is at random times (usualy a build) the controls loose the image in the controls Icon_picturebox.image. and it all needs to be reset.

The text labels are fine. The images are from the project resources.

What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It seems every time you build the project the image in each control reverts to the original controls. It wont retain anything you set it as,.

Comment: remove the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute.  The base PB control already knows how to serialize an image but you are overriding it